# Mistake in a PDE book regarding Lebesgue's differentiation theorem? To do with weak formulation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading "Elliptic and Parabolic Equations" by Wu, Yin and Wang. In Section 4.2, they consider the heat equation given $u_0 \in L^\infty$ and $f \in L^\infty$
$$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
where $u \in H^1(0,T;L^2) \cap L^2(0,T;H^1)$ on a bounded domain. Testing the equation with $(u-k)^+$, where $k$ is larger than the $L^\infty$ norm of $u_0$, and using the fact that $I_k(t) = \int_\Omega |(u(t)-k)^+|^2$ is continuous, so it has a maximum at $t=\sigma$, they derive the following:

[image]

This I don't understand. Here $\sigma$ is NOT a variable, but a particular point in $[0,T]$ which is such that $I_k(\sigma) \geq I_k(t)$ for all $t$ as I mentioned.

They seem to have used Lebesgue's differentiation theorem to obtain the final inequality but that works only for almost all $t \in [0,T]$, and $\sigma$ may lie in the null set. Is there some other way to derive this?

Comment: Would it matter if the final inequality held a.e. with respect to $\sigma$?

Comment: I would like the final inequality to hold for almost every $\sigma \in [0,T]$, it would be enough. But here $\sigma$ is a fixed number (as written above), and not a variable.

Comment: Then it seems wrong, doesn't it? I cannot see why it would be true for a particular $\sigma$.

Comment: Yeah I think it is wrong. I wonder then if it can be true for a.a. $\sigma$.

Comment: I think it is true a.e. [$\sigma$] because of $u\in L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

Comment: Could you explain how? Because the first inequality in the OP holds because we use $I_k(\sigma) - I_k(\sigma - \epsilon) \geq 0$, since $\sigma$ is where $I_k$ takes its maximum.

Comment: Because $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$, then $\nabla u \in L^2(0,T; L^2)$, which means $t\mapsto \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ is in $L^2(0,T)$. Therefore $\int_{0}^{t}\|\nabla u(x,t')\|^2dt'$ is absolutely continuous with $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}\|\nabla u(x,t')\|^2dt'=\|\nabla u(x,t)\|^2$ for a.e. $t\in [0,T]$.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote, but I don't see why that implies the final inequality for a.e. $\sigma$. If we start with the weak formulation integrated over $(0,t)$, we get $\int_\Omega |(u(t)-k)^+|^2 + \int_0^t \int_\Omega |\nabla (u-k)^+|^2 = \int_0^t \int_\Omega f(u-k)^+$. Are you saying we should differentiate this wrt. $t$? But what to do with the first term on the LHS?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\sigma-\epsilon}^{\sigma}f(t)dt \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\sigma-\epsilon}^{\sigma}g(t)dt$. The inequality is preserved in the limit, giving $f(t) \le g(t)$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. If you're saying we take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, then again as we discussed this doesn't make sense for a particular $\sigma$ (unless you're using something other than LEbsgue's differentiation theorem). Please can you give more detail, or an answer?

Comment: The inequality will hold almost everywhere because the derivative exists a.e., but I don't think you can say more than that.